# How to wait for iframe parent to be ready for a postMessage?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, race-condition

How can I, from *within* an iframe, wait until I'm certain that my parent *has* registered its `eventListener:message` *before* attempting to `window.parent.postMessage` to it?

The below code *seems like* it's got a race condition, which (while it *happens* to work without the delay) I've kludged in the 1s delay before sending, to boost reliability.

```
// THIS CODE RUNS IN THE PARENT
window.addEventListener('message',event=>{
  if(event.data==window.localStorage.getItem('expected')||confirm(event.data)) {
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
  }
});
```

```
// THIS CODE RUNS IN THE IFRAME
setTimeout(()=>{
  window.parent.postMessage(document.body.innerText,window.location.origin);
},1000);
```

How could I implement this *deterministically*? I don't want to "just hope" that the code in the parent ran faster than any delays I've set — rather, I'd like to do away with this gross "safety delay" and just have code that's *defined to work*, rather than code that *happens to work*.

Answer (score 1):

How about loading the iframe content AFTER the parent has registered its event listener?

```
window.addEventListener('message', event => { ... });
var iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe");
iframe.src = "/url-to-load-in-iframe";
```

This way you can be certain that event listener is in place, before the iframe starts sending messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee this by having the *parent* (which necessarily has to exist first) wait for some kind of "I'm ready" event emitted by the *child*.

One way to do this is, as the other answer notes, to create the iframe dynamically.

**Another option** is to simply place the parent's `window.addEventLister()` in a synchronous function called *physically before* the `<iframe>` in the DOM, as demo'd here:

```html
<h1>Top-Level Frame</h1>
<script>(async () => {
/* In parent */

// Wait for iframe to reach out to us first
const port2 = await new Promise((res, rej) => {window.addEventListener('message', ev => res(ev.ports[0]), {once: true}); window.addEventListener('messageerror', rej, {once: true});});
port2.postMessage('This message was sent RELIABLY to iframe');

})();</script>

<!-- The script adds the listener SYNCHRONOUSLY before the iframe is even queued -->

<iframe src="data:text/html,
<h2>IFrame</h2>
<script>(() => {
/* In child */

/* Stack Exchange snippet weirdness workaround */
let origin = window.origin ;
if (origin.toString() === 'null') origin = '*';
const documentLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => {if (document.readyState === 'complete') return res(); else {window.addEventListener('load', res, {once: true}); window.addEventListener('error', rej, {once: true});}});

const chan = new MessageChannel();
chan.port1.onmessage = async ev => {
  console.log('got message RELIABLY from parent');
  await documentLoaded;
  let e = document.createElement('p');
  e.textContent = ev.data.toString();
  document.body.appendChild(e);
};
window.parent.postMessage(chan.port2, origin, [chan.port2]);

})();</script>
" />
```